# Vue JS Google OAuth Sign this.$gAuth.isAuthorized always return false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-oauth

This is the code I use to create a Google Client wrapper

```js
var googleAuth = (function () {
  function installClient () {
    var apiUrl = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      var script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = apiUrl
      script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function () {
        if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            resolve()
          }, 500)
        }
      }
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
    })
  }

  function initClient (config) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        window.gapi.auth2.init(config)
          .then(() => {
            resolve(window.gapi)
          })
      })
    })
  }

  function Auth () {
    if (!(this instanceof Auth))
      return new Auth()
    this.GoogleAuth = null /* window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() */
    this.isAuthorized = false
    this.isInit = false
    this.prompt = null
    this.isLoaded = function () {
      /* eslint-disable */
      console.warn('isLoaded() will be deprecated. You can use "this.$gAuth.isInit"')
      return !!this.GoogleAuth
    }

    this.load = (config, prompt) => {
      installClient()
        .then(() => {
          return initClient(config)
        })
        .then((gapi) => {
          this.GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
          this.isInit = true
          this.prompt = prompt
          this.isAuthorized = this.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()
        })
    }

    this.signIn = (successCallback, errorCallback) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!this.GoogleAuth) {
          if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(false)
          reject(false)
          return
        }
        this.GoogleAuth.signIn()
          .then(googleUser => {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') successCallback(googleUser)
            this.isAuthorized = this.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()
            resolve(googleUser)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(error)
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }

    this.getAuthCode = (successCallback, errorCallback) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!this.GoogleAuth) {
          if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(false)
          reject(false)
          return
        }
        this.GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess({ prompt: this.prompt })
          .then(function (resp) {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') successCallback(resp.code)
            resolve(resp.code)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(error)
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }

    this.signOut = (successCallback, errorCallback) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!this.GoogleAuth) {
          if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(false)
          reject(false)
          return
        }
        this.GoogleAuth.signOut()
          .then(() => {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') successCallback()
            this.isAuthorized = false
            resolve(true)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') errorCallback(error)
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }
  }

  return new Auth()
})()

function installGoogleAuthPlugin(Vue, options) {
  //set config
  let GoogleAuthConfig = null
  let GoogleAuthDefaultConfig = { scope: 'profile email', discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'] }
  let prompt = 'select_account'
  if (typeof options === 'object') {
    GoogleAuthConfig = Object.assign(GoogleAuthDefaultConfig, options)
    if (options.scope) GoogleAuthConfig.scope = options.scope
    if (options.prompt) prompt = options.prompt
    if (!options.clientId) {
      console.warn('clientId is required')
    }
  } else {
    console.warn('invalid option type. Object type accepted only')
  }

  //Install Vue plugin
  Vue.gAuth = googleAuth
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $gAuth: {
      get: function () {
        return Vue.gAuth
      }
    }
  })
  Vue.gAuth.load(GoogleAuthConfig, prompt)
}

export default installGoogleAuthPlugin
```

And in `main.js` I used it as follows:

```js
import GoogleAuth from './auth/goauthWrapper.js'
const gauthOption = {
  clientId: 'XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scope: 'profile email',
  prompt: 'select_account'
}
Vue.use(GoogleAuth, gauthOption)
```

I'm able to access `this.$gAuth.signIn()` & `this.$gAuth.signOut()` however, when I try to access  `this.$gAuth.isAuthorized` it is always `false`. Even after successful sign in, the value always `false`

I printed out `this.$gAuth` on Vue `created()` and get the following:
Auth object is this before sign in
[image: Auth before sign in]

Auth object is this after sign in (but I have to manually refresh the page!):
[image: Auth after sign in]

I wonder why I'm unable to access the `this.$gAuth.isAuthorized` when it's `true`?
Do I need to do a *bind*? How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using the listener for it ? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinlistenlistener

Comment: Can you show how/where you're trying to access `this.$gAuth.isAuthorized`?

Comment: @tony19 I'm trying to access that in main.js created() hook. Should I have access it in computed() hook you think?

Comment: `$gAuth` isn't reactive, so using a `computed` prop is unlikely going to help. Do you have a link to reproduction (e.g., in GitHub)?

Comment: @tony19 I used the code from this repository https://github.com/Jebasuthan/Vue-Facebook-Google-oAuth